# How can I use the memory usage tool in the Joomla Debug Console?

Tags: cms, performance, debug

**EDIT:** I've rewritten this question, but the topic is the same.

**How can I use the memory usage tool in the Joomla! Debug Console?** By that I mean, when do people look at this and how do people know when Joomla is using an unusual amount? (especially since there doesn't seem to be any references to compare too?)

Currently my test server is running Joomla 2.5x on Apache with 1 user (me) accessing the site. Memory usage is 18MB of ram. This could be normal, great or poor. I have no idea.

Searching the net, I found some mention of Joomla memory usage at http://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/153-professional-member-support/222168-excessive-resource-use?limitstart=0

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Are you asking for the typical memory usage for a Joomla site for different servers with different server settings and for different versions of Joomla?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit too ambitious. I simply want some sort of reference that I can use to determine whether a site is using an abnormal amount of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't a great answer, and the results you get will be relative, but I'd suggest perhaps installing a vanilla Joomla install on the same server and doing a comparison of output from the memory debug tool. If your main site is eating up memory whilst the vanilla install isn't, gradually load in the same components and data and profile the differences.